# PHP file not moved to directory/folder

Tags: php, file, upload

I'am trying creating upload files which all files extension is allowed, i'm using this code :

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../uploads/assignment/" . $newfilename);
```

The filename is sucessfully inserted to database, files like image or pdf is working but compressed file like .rar or .zip is not moved to the folder

Comment: What are the permissions of the PHP file and the directory you're trying to move the file to?

Comment: no permission, target location folder is `../uploads/assignment/`

Comment: Have you tried an absolute file path instead of relative? i.e. `getcwd() . /uploads/assignment/` instead of `../uploads/assignment/`.

Comment: @Darren idk about path permission, but the folder is located inside the htdocs, all files are succesfully moved, but only .rar type files is not moved to the folder destination